# scipy.optimize.leastsq : not a proper array of floats

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I tried to solve a small toy problem

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def f(a):
    return np.array([a+.2,a-.1])

opt.leastsq(f,2)
```

However, it gives me an error

```
\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    362             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
    363         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
--> 364                 gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    365     else:
    366         if col_deriv:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

But my function f does give an ndarray.

Comment: Judging from the docs, it seems like this should just work. Might be a bug in SciPy.

Comment: try having `f` print `a` and `np.array([a+.2,a-.1])` when called, then exit. See whether the result tallies with the format expected of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

So it needs an array-like input. This works:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def f(a):
    return np.array([a[0]+.2,a[0]-.1])

print opt.leastsq(f,[2])
```